# jfree chart - how to add new item to legend that is not in data source

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am trying to add a new item or label in the legend, this item is not available in dataset. Which method should be used to add this item to legend?

Answer (score 0):

From the [jfree forum](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=11669):

Adding Legends on Bar Chart for custom colors:

```
LegendItemCollection chartLegend = new LegendItemCollection();
Shape shape = new Rectangle(10, 10);
chartLegend.add(new LegendItem("label1", null, null, null, shape, Color.red));
chartLegend.add(new LegendItem("label2", null, null, null, shape, Color.blue));
plot.setFixedLegendItems(chartLegend);
```